# Java LDAP User sinc

Tags: java, algorithm, active-directory, ldap

I am having a problem with implemeting some work with LDAP Using Java. The programm I am writing in Java should take Users from one Active Direcoty, let's call it Dir.1(I am using LDAP, but if you have any other suggestions, I can use some other method) and compare those Users to Contacts in the contact directory on another server, let's call it Dir.2. The programm should take attributes like: DN, CN, SN, mail and isDissabled attributes from a User from Dir.1 and see if there are same users in Dir.2, if there is no user with same info, or the info in Dir.2 of same User is different, the programm copies User from Dir.1 to Dir.2.

It seems pretty easy to do, but since I have never worked with AD, it's not really that easy to me.

I started with the following algorithm
: Connect to the server; parse users and their info from Dir.1 into a Java programm and put everything into a class and into an ArrayList; parse contacts and their info form Dir.2 and put everything into a class and into an ArrayList2; Compare to ArrayLists, matipupate them; "de-code" ArrayLists into Users/Contacts Dirs. and send back to the server.

Now, this algorithm has some weak spots, like [SizeTime Limit] and a lot of unneeded work.  So I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, maybe not parse everything into ArrayLists and Classes and just do everything using just attributes.

I know that this will seem like a stupid question to some LDAP and Ad users, but I am a Java programmer so I don't really know much about LDAP. If anyone can help me, maybe send some pages to read or discribe the algorithm, that would save me for real.

I can send my code if needed

Comment: Why? Active Directory already includes full replication. You shouldn't be implementing this by hand.

Comment: there are 1000s of Users and even more Contacts. I actually have 4 servers to work with. So doing it by hand would be nightmare each time